# Display static pages instead of category, in code

Tags: plugins, php, categories, themes, pages

I'm very new to programming and not sure how to go about this. The following code returns 3 category names and feature images and then outputs them on the page.

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="footer-inside">
        <div id="featured-categories-footer">
            <?php
                $featured_categories = array(8,9,10);
                foreach  ($featured_categories as $featured) {
                    if (get_option(THEME_PREFIX . 'enable_category_' . $featured)) {
                        echo '<!-- featured category #'.$count.' -->';
                        $category_id = get_option(THEME_PREFIX . 'featured_category_' . $featured); 
                        query_posts("cat=$category_id&showposts=1"); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                            <div class="featured-category-footer">
                                <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($category_id); ?>" title="View all posts in <?php echo get_cat_name($category_id); ?>">
                                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                </a>

                                <h3><?php echo get_cat_name($category_id); ?></h3>
                                <?php echo category_description($category_id); ?>
                            </div>  
                        <?php
                        endwhile; endif; 
                        wp_reset_query();
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </div>
```

What I would like to do is, instead of it returning 3 categories that are specified in the admin area, I want to point to three static pages instead. So it will return the feature images for these 3 pages and also the name. Can anyone help please?

I think the line that needs to be changed is '$featured_categories = array(8,9,10);' to point to the pages instead. Am I on the right track here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to change a theme to your own needs?
Since you do not need the categories. etc. You could just drop that whole piece of code starting at

```
<?php     
   $featured_categories = array(8,9,10);
```

Until

```
  wp_reset_query();
                    }
                }
            ?>
```

Next put in your own html code. With links to your pages. Probably 3 times this.

```
<div class="featured-category-footer">
    <a href="link to page">link</a>
     <h3>title</h3>
</div>
```

If you want these pages to come from your wordpress. 
Look into `wp_list_pages` and change it to your needs.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_pages